# How to correlate two AppInsights resources that communicate through NServiceBus?

Tags: .net-core, azure-application-insights, nservicebus

Currently, I have dozens of .NET services hosted on various machines that show up as Resources on my AppInsights Application Map, which also shows their dependencies with respect to each other, based on the HTTP requests they make.

However, the relationships between services that communicate through NServiceBus (RabbitMQ) are not shown. Now, I am able to show the messages that are either sent or handled by a service via calls to `TelemetryClient.TrackXXX()`, but not connect Resources on the map using this information.

I have even gone so far as to attach the parent operation ID from the NSB message sender to the message itself, and assign it to the telemetry object in the receiver, but there is still no line drawn between the services in the Application Map.

To reiterate, this is what I'm getting in the Application Map:

```
(NSB Message Sender) --> (Message sent/handled)
```

And this is what I want:

```
(NSB Sender) --> (Receiver)
```

The services in question are .NET Core 3.1.

I cannot provide the code, as this is for my work, but any help would be greatly appreciated. I've searched everywhere, and even sources that seemed like they would help, didn't.

Comment: Have you looked at [this](https://jimmybogard.com/building-end-to-end-diagnostics-visualizations-with-exporters/) series?

Comment: You can refer to [Building End-to-End Diagnostics: Visualization with Exporters](https://jimmybogard.com/building-end-to-end-diagnostics-visualizations-with-exporters/) and  [Correlate two AppInsights Resources based on NServiceBus communication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/546496/correlate-two-appinsights-resources-based-on-nserv.html)

Comment: @deepdave that second link is this question, posted by myself, in the azure community boards...

Comment: @Sean I dont think this requires delving into the OpenTelemetry stuff under the hood. Our services are auto-instrumented with a call to services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(), with things like NSB calls being manually instrumented

Answer (score 0):

(not signed in, posting from work)

Alright, I finally got it. My approach to correlate AppInsights resources using their NSB communication is to mimic HTTP telemetry correlation.

Below is an extension method I wrote for AppInsights' TelemetryClient. I made a subclass named RbmqMessage:NServiceBus.IMessage, given my applications use RBMQ, and gave it the following properties for the sake of correlation (all set in the service that sends the message) :

- parentId: equal to DependencyTelemetry.Id
- opId: value is the same in the sender's DependencyTelemetry and the receiver's RequestTelemetry. Equal to telemetry.context.operation.id
- startTime: DateTime.Now was good enough for my purposes

The code in the service that sends the NSB message:

```
 public static RbmqMessage TrackRbmq(this TelemetryClient client, RbmqMessage message)
  {
          var msg = message;
          // I ran into some issues with Reflection
          var classNameIdx = message.ToString().LastIndexOf('.') + 1;
          var messageClassName = message.ToString().Substring(classNameIdx);
          var telemetry = new DependencyTelemetry
          {   
                  Type = "RabbitMQ", 
                  Data = "SEND "+messageClassName,
                  Name = "SEND "+messageClassName,
                  Timestamp = DateTime.Now,
                  Target = "RECEIVE "+messageClassName  //matches name in the service receiving this message
           };
           client.TrackDependency(telemetry);
           msg.parentId = telemetry.Id;
           msg.opId = telemetry.Context.Operation.Id; //this wont have a value until TrackDependency is called
           msg.startTime = telemetry.Timestamp;
    
      return msg;
 }
```

The code where you send the NSB message:

```
 var msg = new MyMessage();   //make your existing messages inherit RbmqMessage
 var correlatedMessage = _telemetryClient.TrackRbmq(msg);
 MessageSession.Publish(correlatedMessage);   //or however the NSB message goes out in your application
```

The extension method in the NServiceBus message-receiving service:

```
   public static void TrackRbmq(this TelemetryClient client, RbmqMessage message)
  {
       var classnameIdx = message.ToString().LastIndexOf('.')+1;
       var telemetry = new RequestTelemetry
       {
             Timestamp = DateTime.Now,
             Name = "RECEIVE "+message.ToString().Substring(classNameIdx)
       };
       telemetry.Context.Operation.ParentId = message.parentId;
       telemetry.Context.Operation.Id = message.opId;
       telemetry.Duration = message.startTime - telemetry.Timestamp;
       client.TrackRequest(telemetry);
 }
```

And finally, just track and send the message:

```
 var msg = new MyMessage();
 _telemetryClient.TrackRbmq(msg);
 MessagePipeline.Send(msg);  //or however its sent in your app
```

I hope this saves someone the trouble I went through.

Comment: Hi, I don't know what the telemetry identifier looks like, but NServiceBus stores a ConversationId and CorrelationId inside every single message in the message-headers. Would it be possible to use that, instead of creating your own (or have appinsights client library create a) telemetry id? Otherwise I'd store the identifier in the message headers, not the message body itself.